# Raising average: organic approach vs outlier

Tags: terminology, mean

I'm having trouble articulating a statistics concept concerning averages. As far as I know, there are two ways to raise the average:

- observation by observation (imagine adding +1 to all observations)
- outlier

I'm not so interested in the latter; a freak occurrence, or outlier that raises the average. So I want to say that I'm only interested in the former: observation by observation. For better or worse, I have coined my own word for this: "organic." My rationale coming from the dictionary definition:

> as elements of a an organized whole

**Question:**

Is there an existing term for what I'm trying to articulate? If not, is there a more conventional phrase than "organically"? In other words, I don't want to increase the average from a sparse, infrequent occurrence (a big outlier), but rather from nearly all observations increase to make the average higher.

**Numerical Example**

Suppose we start with a sample that has an average of 5.

```
[5,5,5]
```

Then I say to someone, please increase the average of the sample such that it reaches 100. He/she could show me either of the following:

```
[97, 100, 103]

[5, 5, 270]
```

These samples have the same average, but have very different ranges.

What can I say to imply I only want to raise all values somewhat equally, as in the `[97,100,103]` example.

The best I can do is:

- Please increase the sample average without using an outlier.
- Please increase the sample average while keeping the range within 3
  (or some value)

Neither of which sound particularly refined. I'm hoping there is a better term out there.

### Context

**Example 1**

The situation is business intelligence. After examining the data, I want to give advice to someone -- I want to tell them to increase the average of a certain metric. Here is a simple example:

Imagine a principal says to the teachers of a school: "Increase the average test scores of the students" but he also wants to be more specific so that the teachers don't do something crazy like give one student a 4000% on a test and everyone else 2% or something.

**Example 2**

I think the first example is fairly clear, but there is still the issue of whether A) the teachers are being told to mark more or less generously or B) if it's the teaching methods the teachers enact to help students perform better.

That brings me to example 2. I tried to find a more poignant example:

Let's say there is a fictional policy that requires the mayor or a real estate mogul to increase the average household income of a neighborhood or it will be demolished. Ethics aside, there are two ways of dealing with this, just like in my earlier examples:

- We could offer subsidies to everyone in the neighborhood, UBI style or help them get better jobs in the market
- We could entice a certain Bill Gates to move in to the neighborhood.

Both comply with the fictional policy, but in starkly different ways.

### Conclusion

I did not intend to labor the point so much, but please bear with me. It is very difficult for me to articulate this point, but I hope after these examples you will see why it's important for me to find the correct statistical terminology to bring to light the distinction in how an averages metric is addressed.

Comment: Could you explain what it means to "raise the average"?  This sounds like a purely mathematical question (with the easy solution you have already given), so what would make it statistical?  Are you talking about changing *data*--and if so, why?  And if not data, then what's really going on here?

Comment: @whuber I'm just asking for the proper statistics terminology. By "raise the average" I meant making the sample mean have a larger value.

Comment: Since that's an unusual thing to do--few people think well of anyone modifying their data--I believe it's unlikely there will be "proper terminology" to describe it.  There are, however, similar activities that might have literature and possibly even standard terminology.  These might include *simulating* data, performing *power analyses,* and *disguising* data to avoid revealing sensitive details. Since the methods and terminology vary with the objectives and applications, it would be well to give us some such context for your question.

Comment: @whuber I don't mean to forge the data. I just meant to use it as a business intelligence metric / direction / advice. Imagine, maybe a principal will say to the teachers: "Increase the average test scores of the students." but he also wants to be more specific so that the teachers don't do something crazy like give one student a 4000% on a test and everyone else 20%.

Comment: OK, but (maybe I'm being dense, as usual) I don't understand how this would qualify as business intelligence or even as actionable information.  It sure *looks* like your hypothetical principal is asking teachers to change the data.  The way teachers *ought* to change averages is by executing teaching programs that cause the students to do better on their tests.  At that point, the average will be whatever it turns out to be--but any increase surely won't come about because every student uniformly succeeded in adding $\delta$ points to their score.

Comment: But a suggestion or even instruction to mark more (or less) generously in the future isn't unheard of, however bemused we may feel about it statistically.

Comment: I don't know of any applicable terminology, but maybe it would help to think about a Student's t-test.  The test identifies a difference in means of two groups, but assumes that the variances of the two groups are equal and have distributions of the same shape.  So, the test essentially assumes a *shift* in the distributions between the two groups.  If one group had outliers, it wouldn't fit the assumptions of the test, and so wouldn't be a "valid" difference in the means.

Comment: There is a specific question of terminology bundled here together with a context that several readers have found puzzling or even disturbing. The question on terminology seems easier. It is a basic fact that adding or subtracting a constant to all values moves the mean by precisely that amount. I don't know, and I can't see the point in, devising extra terminology for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get to articulate the point is to replace the wording to reflect what is implied (I use the principal/teacher analogy):

"Please (do something) to increase overall test scores in the next semester."

Now if you introduce outliers to increase the average, you'd contradict the word "overall", since now you *only* increase a few persons' scores while the others remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to say this would be to say

> Please add a constant to each score

There is a term shift used in statistics which would refer to the concept.

The mathematical term translation is also relevant but seems less appealing.

Comment: I had occasion to remark in a review of a statistical book that certain little jokes therein pivoting on detailed knowledge of New York might not translate far from their origin.